# Changes in declared length of stay vs authorized stay in Canada

Tags: canada

I used the kiosk machine in YVR and indicated that I intended to stay for 3 weeks. For some reasons, my return flight was cancelled so I decided to just buy a new return ticket. I also extended my vacation to 2 months instead of the original 3 weeks.
Will this be an issue on my future trips to Canada? Please note that I didn’t get any stamps upon entry (so it means 6 months of authorized stay?)
Is this considered a misrepresentation or overstaying?

Comment: Did you apply for a visa for this trip? It won't matter in most cases.

Comment: People's travel plans change for any number of unforseen reasons. On several pre-electronic arrivals at YVR I was stamped with the routine 3 months regardless of wht my stated plans were.

Comment: [Most visitors to Canada are admitted for 6 months](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16) and that is the default if they don't stamp another date. Staying significantly longer than you said might at worst be a small negative when they consider your next entry; doing that repeatedly might make it a bigger negative.

Comment: Hi weather vane, did you use kiosk in yvr? We never got a stamp, just a small paper receipt from the kiosk (not sure if that’s the stamp nowadys?)

Comment: I wrote "pre-electronic arrivals". They didn't care very much what my travel plans were, only to know if I was a reasonable person to allow in.

Answer (score 3):

This [Canada Immigration FAQ page](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16) from April 7, 2022, says:

> **How long can I stay in Canada as a visitor?**
>
> ...
>
> Most visitors can stay for up to 6 months in Canada.
>
> If you’re allowed to enter Canada, the border services officer may allow you to stay for less or more than 6 months.
>
> • If so, they’ll put the date you need to leave by in your passport. They might also give you a document.
>
> •If you don’t get a stamp in your passport, you can stay for 6 months from the day you entered Canada or until your passport expires, whichever comes first.
>
> ...

Thus: because you didn't get a stamp in your passport upon entering Canada, you are authorized to stay for 6 months or until your passport expires, whichever comes first.

Comment: Thank you. So the declared number of days doesn’t matter?

Comment: @animotrvl Yes, provided no stamp was placed in your passport.

Comment: @animotrvl you may have follow up questions on your next visit inquiring why you stayed that much longer (we’re talking x3 here), especially if you come back to Canada shortly after you leave or if there is any doubt you could have been doing unauthorised activities (e.g. working) during your stay (for instance if staying for 2 months without working seems to be beyond your means). In other words, by itself, it’s not a problem, but it may raise suspicion, depending on your circumstances.

Comment: @jcaron Hi! Only stayed 2 months out of 6 months (authorized stay) but again I only declared 3 weeks during entry.

Comment: @xngtng Yes, I have a multiple entry visitor visa.